# could use some assistance dealing with a situation related to python

Tags: python, list, replace, names

So im new at python and i would like some help in making code where:
When an input is typed if the input has a minimum of three words that match any one thing on a list it would replace the input with the text in the list that matches the criteria

Example: 
Jan
-Scans List-
-Finds Janice-
-Replaces and gives output as Janice Instead of Jan-
Janice

So far

```
getname = []
for word in args
 room.usernames.get(args,word)
```

Room.usernames is the list and args input

Error List item has no attribute .get

there is a module used and its ch.py located at http://pastebin.com/5BLZ0UA0

Comment: Could you show us, what you have tried so far? People are very helpful, but usually they don't write complete programs for you. However, if you show us what approach you have taken so fare, you are very likely to receive help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to:

- make a replacement words dictionary
- get some input
- do sanity checking to make sure it fits your parameters
- split it into a `list`
- loop through your new `list` and replace each word with its replacement in your `dict`, if it is in there

I won't write all of this for you.  But here's a tip for how to do that last part: use the `get` method of dicts - it allows you to provide a "fallback" in case the word is not found in the `dict`.  So just fall back to the word itself.

```
replacement_words = {'jan':'janice','foo':'bar'}
my_list = ['jan','is','cool']

[replacement_words.get(word,word) for word in my_list]
Out[41]: ['janice', 'is', 'cool']
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could try this

```
getname = []
for word in args
  "%s"% (room.usernames).get(args,word)
```